# Struggling with split text with number in between 1 to 45 using regex in java

Tags: java, arrays

i am struggling with splitting the whole text starting with number and followed by it text
so the number is in between 01 to 45,can be possibility with any either 04 or 4

> **09** Software for use in assisted driving of railway vehicles; software for electronic railway driving assistance systems; hardware for electronic railway driving assistance systems; driver assistance systems for railway vehicles. **37** Installation and replacement services for railway vehicles, railway vehicles that incorporate driver assistance systems in the detection and avoidance of excessive speed, obstacles, vehicles and people; Software installation and replacement services for railway driving assistance systems and vehicle network coordination centers **42** Supervision services for driving. assistance; systems for railway vehicles; checking railway vehicles; checking railway vehicles that incorporate driver assistance systems

Required output as per below array list.

```
index[0]=09 Software for use in assisted driving of railway vehicles; software for electronic railway driving assistance systems; hardware for electronic railway driving assistance systems; driver assistance systems for railway vehicles.
index[1]=37 Installation and replacement services for railway vehicles, railway vehicles that incorporate driver assistance systems in the detection and avoidance of excessive speed, obstacles, vehicles and people; Software installation and replacement services for railway driving assistance systems and vehicle network coordination centers
index[2]=42 Supervision services for driving. assistance; systems for railway vehicles; checking railway vehicles; checking railway vehicles that incorporate driver assistance systems
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is sample code that does what you want:

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "09 Software for use in assisted driving of railway vehicles; software for electronic railway driving assistance systems; hardware for electronic railway driving assistance systems; driver assistance systems for railway vehicles. 37 Installation and replacement services for railway vehicles, railway vehicles that incorporate driver assistance systems in the detection and avoidance of excessive speed, obstacles, vehicles and people; Software installation and replacement services for railway driving assistance systems and vehicle network coordination centers 42 Supervision services for driving. assistance; systems for railway vehicles; checking railway vehicles; checking railway vehicles that incorporate driver assistance systems";

        // split on numbers 
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s*(?:\\d+)\\s*");
        String[] arr = p.split(s);

        // capture the numbers seperately
        String[] numbers = p.matcher(s).results().map(m -> m.group().strip()).toArray(String[]::new);

        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%s: \"%s\"\n", numbers[i-1], arr[i]);// first split is empty, so first string is at index 1

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why give code to someone who's shown zero effort?